# php concatenating string to classconstant in array assignment

Tags: php, arrays, class-constants

following doesn't work:

```
<?php
class test{
    const t = 10;
    public static $y = array('t' => self::t . 'hello');
}
var_dump(test::$y);
?>
```

can somebody tell me why that is? :)

it fails in the ... => self::t . 'hello')... part, where it, as seams, not is able to concatenate a classconstant in the array().

that implies that both of following works perfect:

```
public static $y = array('t' => self::t);
```

and

```
public static $y = array('t' => 'hello');
```

Comment: Always add your error message. And if you paste it into the search box even, you will get ca. 999 questions which are similar, if not even exactly like yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can somebody tell me why that is?

Concatenation is a product of run-time. Class member initial values must be known at parse time.